# Alteryx installation triggering dependency confusion attack alerts with ORCA

Tags: security, npm, pypi, alteryx

I have an instance of Alteryx Designer installed on a VM hosted in Azure. Recently, I have been using ORCA for cloud security and have been receiving an alert about a potential NPM and PyPi dependency confusion for the following packages:

- ayx-insights
- ayx-chart-editor-tool
- eslint-config-ayx-ui-base
- ayx-ui-sdk
- eslint-config-ui-core-base
- npm-dev-artifact

I have tried updating and reinstalling, but this does not fix the issue. I assume it is because these packages are not included in the public NPM or PyPi registries. I'm unable to find any information on the Alteryx website and searching both the Alteryx and ORCA tags here did not return results. I was wondering if this is something others have dealt with and what the best course of action was to correct it.